# Would you mind to advise about next step to be a good developer?

Tags: developer

All.

I want to hear your advise about what's the next step to be a good developer. I'm a junior developer using java and I have been a salesforce consultant and developer for 2years at partner company.

Last 2 years, I learned about salesforce and what a value of Salesforce. So, I have studied hard to get the salesforce certifications.
- Salesforce Certified Administrator
- Salesforce Certified Sales Consultant
- Salesforce Certified Service Consultant
- Salesforce Certified Platform Develper1

Now, My goal is two path.
First one is to get a certification, Salesforce certified Technical Architect. I want to know Salesforce and build relevant development knowledge so that my clients can adopt Salesforce efficiently and effectively. What is the best way to help me earn this certificate in my current status?

Last one is to become a developer working in Salesforce.
I want to be a developer who give good influences to many people using Salesforce. How can I prepare?

Best Regards, CJ Sohn.

Comment: Am not sure if this is the right place to ask these kinds of question, it might have opiniated answer. I feel its more suited for Reddit twitter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very much an opinion, but I suggest you also learn from outside the Salesforce world e.g. [12 Most Influential Books Every Software Engineer Needs to Read](https://jasonroell.com/2015/03/16/12-most-infuential-books-every-software-engineer-needs-to-read/). Plenty of great ideas out there.

Personal favorites are:

- "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin
- "Refactoring" (second edition, uses JavaScript) by Martin Fowler
- "Advanced Apex Programming" by Dan Appleman (OK, this is Salesforce specific)